# In react-native trying to achieve category picker which on selected value returns it's multiple subcategory values

Tags: select, react-native, categories, picker

In react-native trying to achieve category picker which on selected value returns it's multiple subcategory values. So, I have my category tree in the state which now has three levels. What I want to achieve is how to select a category (in picker) which then changes picker values to subcategory values and so on. All selected categories (and subcategories) will be pushed in another state value and outputted as a indicators list.

Heres my code:

```
  constructor(props) {//state with categories
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: [],
      categories: [
        {
          name: 'categoryName',
          value: 'categoryName',
          field: 'E',
          options: [
            {
              name: 'subCategoryName',
              value: 'subCategoryName',
              field: 'F',
              options: [
                {
                  name: 'subSubCategoryName',
                  field: 'H'
                },
                {
                  name: 'subSubCategoryName',
                  field: 'H'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

//filter function
      categoryFilter() {
        return(
          <View style={{ flex:1, marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <Picker // here onValueChange I need to update my category picker so when selected it could display my category's subcategory picker items
              style={{ flex:1 }}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({category: [...this.state.category, itemValue]})}>
              {this.state.categories.map(category => {
                return(
                  <Picker.Item label={category.name} value={category.value} />
                );
              })}
            </Picker>
            <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 40, marginTop: 10 }}>
              <View style={{ flex:5, backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 8, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                {this.state.category.map(category => {
                  return(
                    <Text>{ this.state.category.name }</Text>//this should be a list of selected category values like this: CategoryName subCategoryName subSubCategoryName
                  );         
                })}
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 18, padding: 8, backgroundColor: '#faa320', textAlign: 'center' }}>{'>'}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
```